# Post to Django form from java client vs curl -d

Tags: java, forms, request

I am stuck with an issue here. I'm trying to make a request to a Django API from a Java application. I have a curl command from the command line that works like a charm... but, from java I can't get it right. So... The curl comand:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'username=clientname&password=somepassword' 'https://hostname.domain/api/v1/login'
```

This gets me a response body like:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Login OK",
  "token": "iLCJhbGcoOIJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiU0ZMT1JFUy...(truncated)"
}
```

My Java code

```
public Optional<String> login() {

    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("username", USER);
    form.param("password", PASS);

    Entity<Form> requestEntity = Entity.form(form);
    WebTarget target = this.client.target(LOGIN_URL);
    Response response = target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(requestEntity);

    this.logger.info(String.format("Response status: %s", response));

    if (response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
        LoginResponseDTO loginDTO = response.readEntity(LoginResponseDTO.class);
        return Optional.<String>of(loginDTO.getToken());
    } else {
        this.logger.warn(String.format("%s", response.getStatusInfo()));
        this.logger.warn(String.format("Cannot log user '%s' in", USER));
        return Optional.<String>empty();
    }

}
```

The java code, when invoked, is getting back a BadRequest response. I've checked the Django log and the body of the POST seems to be empty, but the request in java, carries the form passed as body. If anyone has some hint about what am I missing, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well... turns out jersey client default config gzips the body... The target API did not support that.

In the application 'run' method I added:

```
    JerseyClientConfiguration clientConfig = new JerseyClientConfiguration();
    clientConfig.setGzipEnabled(false);
    clientConfig.setGzipEnabledForRequests(false);

    Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment).using(clientConfig).build("RESTClient");

    this.petiteBundle.getPetiteContainer().addBean(Client.class.getName(), client);
```

Took me a while to see this, but i was able to realize this was happening after activating the requests payload dump in the 'run' method of the application with:

```
    environment.jersey().register(
            new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger("Main application"), Level.INFO, Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, 100000));
```